# Set cookie lifetime in phtml

Tags: magento2, cookie, object-manager

I want to set the `cookie lifetime` in my phtml file.

I am using the following code:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cookieManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface');
$cookieMetadataFactory = \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory::getInstance();
$cookie_lifetime = (90 * 60);//90 days
$cookie_metadata = $cookieMetadataFactory->createPublicCookieMetadata()->setDuration($cookie_lifetime); 
$cookieManager->setPublicCookie('cookie1', 'value', $cookie_metadata);
```

I get this error:

> Call to undefined method 
>   Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory::getInstance()

So, is there no getInstance method? What can I use instead?

Comment: please accept the answer if my answer worked for you

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly get instance for `Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory`  instead use

`$cookieMetadataFactory = $objectManager->get("Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory");`

However, you should probably using dependency injection of your constructor if you are in block or controller, make a function in block in case of phtml as objectmanager is not a recommended practice.